# Subsetting records

Tags: sas

I have a table that looks like this:

> ```
>  Country  
>
>  Austria     
>  Belgium      
>  Germany      
>  Italy      
>  ....
> ```

I'm trying to subset some records (Austria and Belgium) of the variable Country in this way but it does not work:

> ```
>  DATA mydata;        
>     SET mydata;       
>     KEEP Austria Belgium;       
>     RUN;
> ```

I used this piece of code from here https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/ubsetting-data-in-sas/ where some examples of subsetting data are reported. Unfortunately it does not work.

Can anyone help me please? I'm new in SAS.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a sub-setting if

```
DATA mydata;        
    SET mydata;       
    if country in ('Austria', 'Belgium');       
RUN;
```

You have to check if the variables equals those values.  What you have in your code is telling SAS to keep **columns** `Austria` and `Belguim` in the output data.  Those are values, not columns.